# Use managed navigation and structured navigation together?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, managed-navigation

Is it possible to use managed navigation in conjunction with structured navigation?

I have a page I would like to give a friendly URL to, but from what I've read, that requires having managed navigation enabled.  The article I read said I have two choices: managed navigation or structured navigation.  The implication I got from that was I can use one or the other, but not both.

I would like to keep structured navigation for the rest of my site, but set up a friendly URL for this one page (using managed navigation).

Answer (score 0):

We cannot combine managed navigation and structured navigation. We only can use one of them.

And the navigation settings can work for one site not for a page.

There is a workaround.

You could enable tree view in the site settings. It will display all site contents. Go to site settings->look and feel->Navigation Elements.

And you could select managed navigation in the navigation settings.

After all, the result will be the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for, because I can add links to the managed navigation that would effectively work the same as tree view.  I appreciate you commenting and answering anyway.  The Y problem to the X problem in my question is that I want to enable someone to send a URL out to an email group, and not have the ugly SharePoint URL.  I guess we'll have to stick with hyperlinked text.